# Should I use broadcast receiver inside a recycler view row to update download progress of that item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks

I've a recycler view which does download list items. I can think of two ways to update the state of a row at nth pos -

- I can create a method in adapter to update ArrayList item at nth pos and set it's progress. I'm wanting to avoid it as I'm using room live data so I don't want to update the rows directly as any change to db would revert the update I made.
- I can register broadcast receiver in each download list item when user clicks download btn and send progress broadcast from download service. But it will create problem when scrolled. Also there's a problem in unregistering the receiver in row as I won't be sure when to do.

Suggest the right way of doing it? Recycler view is not fixed so I need to make sure on scroll it doesn't flicker or shows wrong progress.

Comment: one way I can think of registering the broadcast receiver in activity and update each adapter item, calling notifyItemChanged(pos). This way you have a finer control over the registration/unregistration of the broadcast. Keeping this in each row item is any way not a solution.

Comment: But the problem is if any item is changed in db it'll reset the state of all rows as I'm using room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved simply creating broardcase receiver as instance variable on holder and storing the reference so that I can unregister when Activity is destroyed. This also solved memory leak issue.